# Replace all string values to '1'

Tags: r, string, replace, numeric

I have a dataframe in R in which all cells either contain '0' or a word (short string of 4-6 letters). I would like to replace all these string values to '1'. I see a lot of options replacing specific words or characters, but as I have many different words, I would simply like to say something like 'replace all string values to numeric '1').

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("0","a","short","sentence")

as.numeric(x != "0")
[1] 0 1 1 1
```

To work with a data.frame, you have to loop over the columns using `lapply` and convert back:

```
y <- data.frame(x,x,x)
data.frame(lapply(y, function(x) as.numeric(x!="0")))
  x x.1 x.2
1 0   0   0
2 1   1   1
3 1   1   1
4 1   1   1
```

Comment: better (imo): `as.numeric(x != "0")`

Comment: you also need to incorporate an example with data.frame @James

Answer (score 1):

assuming `df` is your data. assuming your strings were all `character` variables

```
df = data.frame(a = c("joel", "0", "wilso"), b = c(1:3))
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
df[df != '0']='1'
df
#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 0 1
#3 1 1
```

---

```
df = data.frame(a = c("j", "0", "w"), b = c(1:3), 
                c = 4:6, d = c("eng", "0", "aus"))

data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) { 
                         if(is.factor(x)) {
                           x <- as.character(x)
                         }
                         x[x!="0"]="1"
                         x}))
#  a b c d
#1 1 1 1 1
#2 0 1 1 0
#3 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 replace(x, x!="0", 1)
```

Or just

```
as.integer(x!= "0")
```

---

If we have a data.frame

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.integer(x!="0"))
```